# how to obtain related models after mergeBindings is called (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query:

```
$oeTrienios = Trienio::with('curso');

foreach (Session::get('trienios') as $trienio) {
    $oeTrienios = $oeTrienios->where('data_trienio', $trienio->trienio)->whereHas('curso', function ($query) use ($trienio) {
        $query->where('curso', $trienio->curso);
    });
}

$union = Trienio::with('curso')->whereHas('curso', function ($query) use ($coordinatedCourse) {
    $query->where('curso', $coordinatedCourse);
})->union($oeTrienios);

$trienios = \DB::table(\DB::raw("({$union->toSql()}) as trienios"))
            ->mergeBindings($union->getQuery());
```

The query is working fine, it gets the `Trienio` models, however, after mergeBindings being called the related `Curso` models "disappear". How can I call them again?

P.S - `mergeBindings()` is required in the final query. I can't remove it.

Comment: You probably need to do old-fashioned joins. Eloquent relationships work a bit differently.

Comment: how can I do that?